# How can I get redirect_to to kick in if a user clicks the submit button on a form 3 times in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement a feature where a user is redirected to the homepage of my website if they click a submit button on a form (login or signup) more than 3-5 times.

I can't seem to think of a way to do this.

Comment: Instead of doing this, just post the form over AJAX and disable the form so the user can't post it again.

Comment: Or just submit the form as normal and disable all the fields using JS.

Comment: check this: https://github.com/ejfinneran/ratelimit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are really talking about users that depress the same submit button 3-5 times on a single form.

If you want to make sure that a user presses the submit-button only once, you can use

```
= f.button :submit, :disable_with => 'Please wait ...'
```

which disables the button after the first press.
This does not limit the user if after first submission, he enters the form again and tries again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but a good alternative which I'm now using thanks.